# Как можно заменить с помощью JavaScript css-свойство backdrop-filter: blur();?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Нужно заменить css-свойство backdrop-filter: blur(); ибо оно поддерживается не всеми браузерами.
Также я прикрепил пример, смотрите на меню

Comment: что делает этот фильтр?

Comment: Делайте обычный фильтр и создайте либо ещё один элемент который сзади будет, либо через псевдо элемент попробуйте.

Comment: https://www.google.ru/search?q=polyfill+backdrop-filter

Comment: @ΝNL993 я прикрепил пример (фото), посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: @grvmmy. Ну а в чём проблема? Просто делайте `blur` для элемента который находится на фоне, что не так?